# html form: js submit() with predefined value

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to use a html form without a submit button.
I use submit() but I somehow fail to set a default value:

```
<form id="form" action="index.php" method="post">
        <select name="date" size="1" onclick="javascript: submitform()" value="201601291010">
<option value="201601291010">2016-01-29 10:10 UTC</option>
<option value="201601291000">2016-01-29 10:00 UTC</option>
<option value="201601290950">2016-01-29 09:50 UTC</option>
        </select>

</form>     

<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform() 
{
  document.getElementById('form').submit();
}
</script>

<?php $date = $_POST['date']; echo ("date is $date"); ?>
```

$date is empty at load time. how do i set $date to "201601291010" at load time and to be redefined by onclick?

Comment: have you tried setting up in your submitform() function before you call .submit() ?

Comment: yes, it makes no difference

Answer (score 0):

If you truly want to submit with the default value then utilize the onload event.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     submitform(); // this fires as soon as the page loads
     // if you want to wait until the user selects an option then
     // remove the above and uncomment the below.

     //$("#date").change(function(){
     //    submitform();
     //});
});

function submitform(){
    alert($("#date").val()); //alert to let you see the default value, remove as needed
    document.getElementById('form').submit();
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form" action="index.php" method="post">
    <select id="date" name="date" size="1">
        <option selected="selected" value="201601291010">2016-01-29 10:10 UTC</option>
        <option value="201601291000">2016-01-29 10:00 UTC</option>
        <option value="201601290950">2016-01-29 09:50 UTC</option>
   </select>

 </form>     
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Then the variable is still undefined at loadtime, it's only defined when i change the selection. With "option selected" the value is selected in the form, but not submitted at loadtime

Comment: if you want it to submit right at load time, then set the onload event and fire it from there. this will most likely not even let you see the screen since it will submit as soon as it's done loading.

Comment: still undefined at load time. i'm too old for this

Comment: Just noticed your question is about understanding php. Take a look at this link to see it explained.  Php loads on the server before the page is loaded.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792475/does-php-load-before-the-html-body

Comment: thank you. got it working by defining the variable in php if empty